# oData case insensitive filter contains

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, odata

Is there a setting/configuration in .Net Core 2.2 where we can make oData queries to the backend like this and it would ignore the case? In the example below I would like all Cars with Brand FORD and Ford to appear in the search results

```
https://localhost/api/cars?$filter=contains(Brand,'FoRd')
```

I'm aware you can use toLower in the URL but I'm looking at a setting in the backend

Comment: You can check this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1227943/Case-Insensitive-Search-Filter-in-OData-ASP-NET-Co) , but in my testing with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` verion `7.2.2` , it works as case insensitive by default . Not sure what is the cause .

Comment: I just tried with version 7.2.2 and I get the same case sensitive behavior on the "filter contains" operation

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Nan Yu's comment, I figured the reason for that example to work as case-insensitive is that instead of using an expression like:

`contains(Name,'Dom')`

they use:

`contains(tolower(Name),'dom')`

Do note that the field name (in this case `Name`) is prefixed with an OData's function call `toLower()` and the string `'Dom'` has been manually lowered to `'dom'`.

Comment: In my project I used a filter like this:
`https://localhost/api/cars?$filter=contains(tolower(Brand),tolower('FoRd'))`